# Simple HTTP Server SSL record_too_long error

Tags: python, ssl, pyopenssl

I am trying to run a few Python CGI scripts using CGIHTTPServer. This works fine, but now I'd like to run using SSL on the Web listener.

I started with the solution at [Activestate code recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442473-simple-http-server-supporting-ssl-secure-communica/) and changed SimpleHTTPRequestHandler to CGIHTTPRequestHandler. This works fine serving static files, including the cgi scripts (cgi-bin is, for now, a link to ".") but for cgi scripts Firefox shows

> "SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length"
>
> Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long.

Web searches indicate this is likely a server issue, not browser, which seems logical to me. Also, I've tried all the suggested browser settings. I've tried a variety of server settings also, but no joy.

- Platform is RHEL 2.6.18
- Python is 2.4.3 - please don't suggest using "`import ssl`" as it isn't available
- Self signed certificate, accepted in browser (static files work)

code:

```
import socket, sys    
import SocketServer
import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
from OpenSSL import SSL


class SecureHTTPServer(BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass):
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        SockeServer.BaseServer.__init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass)
        ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
        ctx.use_privatekey_file ("path/key.pem")
        ctx.use_certificate_file("path/cert.pem")
        self.socket = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(self.address_family,                                                       self.socket_type))
        self.server_bind()
        self.server_activate()

class SecureHTTPRequestHandler(CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    def setup(self):
        self.cgi_directories= ['cgi-bin']
        self.connection = self.request
        self.rfile = socket._fileobject(self.request, "rb", self.rbufsize)
        self.wfile = socket._fileobject(self.request, "wb", self.wbufsize)

def test(HandlerClass = SecureHTTPRequestHandler, ServerClass = SecureHTTPServer):
    httpd = ServerClass(('0.0.0.0',4443), HandlerClass)
    sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
    print "Serving HTTPS on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "..."
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

How may I get this working for a quick and easy web interface in Python 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

Wound up using Apache httpd to get SSL working with the existing Python CGI scripts. I'd still like to know how to get it working with the CGIHTTPServer class, though